# Avoid ansible to load Dockerfile and other yml

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile

I need to synchronize (rsync) some Dockerfile, and also other .yml to remote machines.
Those files are under "host_vars/" folder.

When running the simple "synchronize" ansible command Dockerfile is read and error is raised due Dockerfile is not yml format ... (drama!).
Also, if I need to deploy a docker-compose.yml another error is raised

There is a way to tell ansible to not load some selected files?

Setting a different names it not works.

Dockerfile error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected <document start>

The error appears to have been in '/.../Dockerfile line 4, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


RUN apt update && apt install -y graphite-carbon graphite-web nginx supervisor && apt-get autoclean
^ here
```

docker-compose.yml error

```
ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'list': 
....
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That seems like an unusual setup: typically the `Dockerfile` would be treated as part of application source code, and it'd be in the source repository (checked out with other source code in a developer setup, not installed at all in a production setup).  For more production-oriented use you'd push an image to a Docker registry and use the `docker_container` module to start a container from it, without rebuilding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to synchronize (rsync) some Dockerfile, and also other .yml to remote machines.
>   Those files are under "host_vars/" folder.

It is inappropriate to put non-vars files in a folder called `host_vars`. Ansible expects all files found in `host_vars` and `vars` to be either JSON or yaml formatted key-value pairs that it will use to create implicit variables.

If you want to bundle up files to travel along with your role, put them in the `files` folder; if they are parameterized, put them in the `templates` folder, as one can see from [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure).